# Repeated aggregation of rows into a single row

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data,

```
var1 <- c("101299, 13-132, 13-,", "101299, 12-12, 15-," , "101300, 13-132, 13-,", "101300, 12-12, 15-,")
data <- data.frame(var1)
str(data)
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) -> data
data
> data
                  var1
1 101299, 13-132, 13-,
2  101299, 12-12, 15-,
3 101300, 13-132, 13-,
4  101300, 12-12, 15-,
```

The variable consists of characters. I want to add every second (or some other number) row with the first row. The end result should look like this,

```
var1
101299, 13-132, 13-, 101299, 12-12, 15-,
101300, 13-132, 13-, 101300, 12-12, 15-,
```

Any hint how to do this?

**Addition:**

As suggested in the comment below, one way to solve this, is

```
data4 <- cbind(data[1:2-1,], data[3:4,])
```

It generates the table I want. However, is it possible do that in a more abstract way so that I can use that in a large dataset? For example, instead of adding 1 row, I want to add 10 rows into 1 and want to repeat that 1000 times.

Comment: base R solutions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010447/combine-two-consecutive-rows-in-a-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you @PoGibas. The solution is creating 3 rows from 4. I want two rows. That means 2nd row should be joined with 1st row, 4th row should be joined with 3rd row.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you don't like about the `cbind(data[1:2-1,], data[3:4,])` solution - fairly easy to generate the right row indices for any case, right? Can you maybe share a *slightly* bigger example to show what you mean by *"I want to add 10 rows into 1 and want to repeat that 1000 times."*? Perhaps show an example "adding 3 rows into 1 and repeating 4 times" to illustrate...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data <- data %>% mutate(index = 1:nrow(data))

second_rows <- data %>% filter(., index%%2==0) %>% rename(var2=var1)
first_rows <- data[data$index %in% (second_rows$index - 1),] 

df <- cbind(first_rows, second_rows)[, c(1,3)]
df %>% mutate(new_var = paste(var1, var2)) %>% select(new_var)
```

If you want to change the format to use every third, or whatever rows, you change index%%2==0 to index%%3==0, etc.

Comment: Thank you. I tried your snippet on this data, 
`var1 <- c("10, 20", 
          "30, 40",
          "50, 60",
          "70, 80",
          "90, 100",
          "110, 120")
data <- data.frame(var1)
library(dplyr)
data %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) -> data`
I set `index%%3==0`. I was expecting 2 rows. Row1: 10 20 30 40 50 60, Row2: 70, 80, 90, 1001 110, 120. Instead I am getting this, 
`     var1     var2
2  30, 40   50, 60
5 90, 100 110, 120 `
What did I do wrong here?